# How to remove default marker when replace new icon marker on Google map

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm use icon marker to replace default marker of google map, but i use icon marker png, i cannot remove default marker..

**This is Script:**

```
    function myMap() {

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  <c:forEach var="list" items="${latlongList}" varStatus="status">
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(<c:out value="${list.latCust}"/>,<c:out value="${list.longCust}"/>),
      pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(<c:out value="${list.latDsc}"/>,<c:out value="${list.longDsc}"/>),
  </c:forEach>

  mapProp = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: pointA,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
  },
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapProp),
  // Instantiate a directions service.
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });

  var iconStart = {
            url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/images/common/icon-pin-02.svg',
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(42, 52), // scaled size
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
  };
  var iconEnd = {
          url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/images/common/icon-pin-01.svg',
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(39, 49), // scaled size
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
  };

  markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pointA,
    map: map,
    icon: iconStart
  });

  markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pointB,
    map: map,
    icon: iconEnd
  });
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      computeTotalDistance(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {

var totalDist = 0;
var totalTime = 0;
var myroute = result.routes[0];
var priceFee = 0;

for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
}
```

}

**Photo**:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I have try to find some guide but it seem cannot remove, anyone can support me
How to remove default marker ? many thanks

[commentttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace A and B markers in Google Map Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685974/how-to-replace-a-and-b-markers-in-google-map-api)

Comment: related question: [How can i remove origin and destination marker but still retain white little circle point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191151/how-can-i-remove-origin-and-destination-marker-but-still-retain-white-little-cir)

Comment: `suppressMarkers:true`

Comment: Thank @geocodezip, i will try to update with this parameter

Answer (score -1):

You can't just use an `svg` via the `url` option. This has to be either inline or you create your own glyph for it, see [graphic-markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/graphic-markers).

Another option is to use a `png` grafic instead of the `svg`.